# Why did a Korean business executive title "태산" (Mount Tai) on her business card?

Tags: sino-korean-words

[image]

##### My boss's Korean friend gave me her business card, pictured above. Why did she headline with 태산?

I blued out her address and telephone number that are correct. Her Korean name  is not 태산. She and her business have nothing to do with mountains or Mount Tai! She appears too old for mountains.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%ED%83%9C%EC%82%B0) lists 2 meanings for 태산 (Hanja for [泰山](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Tai), Mount Tai, in China) has 2 meanings

> 1. great mountain, tall mountain
> 2. (figurative) huge amount; a mountain (of)

that  are affirmed by [HiNative](https://hinative.com/questions/22501662#answer-52179362), [National Institute of Korean Language](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/m/eng/searchResultView?wordMatchFlag=N&currentPage=1&mainSearchWord=%EC%82%B0&sort=W&searchType=W&proverbType=&exaType=&ParaWordNo=20954&font_size=12&nationCode=6&nation=eng&viewType=A), [Naver](https://korean.dict.naver.com/koendict/#/entry/koen/3c3d9f3f35fc49a4b7bf95ff197269bc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely just the name of a small business.  If you search for 태산 부동산 (realtor) for example, you see at least a dozen places named 태산 부동산 or 태산 공인 중개사 all over the country.

There is one listed as "건축/인테리어/부동산/청소 >> 건축·인테리어 >> 건설-종합건축 ... [**(주)태산**], xxxx-xxxx ..." which pops up if you google "태산 부동산 서울 흥인동".  It seems to be an old listing for a small real estate and interior construction business but it has no further details -- it could be that they no longer exist or they have shut down the web site if there ever was one.

Real estate offices are very numerous and they come and go all the time. They could use anything as their name including the name of any mountain or river in any country.  태산 is probably more popular because of its traditional association with a massive amount of something.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with the mountain in China. "태산," yes, with the same Chinese characters, is a common Korean word meaning a "huge mountain" or figuratively a "huge pile of something," and has been used for the name of the business. The business owner probably wished their business to be *great in scale* (that is, "泰") and successful, naming so. Naming a business after a natural object is a common practice -- a little old-fashioned though.

Comment: I think it has at least *a little* to do with the Chinese mountain.  Most likely, Koreans borrowed the word from Classical Chinese, where the word referred to the mountain, and then the meaning gradually shifted to "something huge" until most people forgot that it once meant an actual mountain.